# Identify this sapling tree

Tags: identification, trees

I saved this individual from the footpath in a nature reserve in Stellenbosch, South Africa and planted it in my garden. What species of tree is it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to me like a *Dais continifolia*, or pompon tree, judging by the leaf colour and venation. See http://pza.sanbi.org/dais-cotinifolia for more info, although it is more distinctive when in flower.

Comment: thank you. Does the sapling look healthy to you? The larger leaves look stressed, but since it's growing new leaves at the top I suppose it's going to make it?

Comment: Looks pretty healthy to me.  No worries unless something changes in the next few weeks